# MemoryError while using scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with a little over 200,000 rows and 337 columns. I am using five of those columns for prediction on a sixth column. When I try to fit/train my algorithm using:

```
predictors = [
    'RO5', 'RO3', 'RO6',
    'CS5', 'income'
]
selector = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=5)
selector.fit(data[predictors], data['ED2'])

scores = -np.log10(selector.pvalues_)

alg = RandomForestClassifier(
    random_state=1,
    n_estimators = 20,
    min_samples_split = 8,
    min_samples_leaf = 3
)
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(alg, data[predictors], data["ED2"], cv=3)
print(scores.mean())
```

I get a memory error for both `RandomForestClassifier` and `SelectKBest`. How can I work around this to remove the error and train my algorithm?

**COMPLETE TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\major\solution-1.py", line 234, in <module>
    prep_data()
  File "F:\major\solution-1.py", line 160, in prep_data
    selector.fit(data[predictors], data['ED2'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1963, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2008, in _getitem_array
    return self.take(indexer, axis=1, convert=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1368, in take
    self._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2411, in _consolidate_inplace
    self._protect_consolidate(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2402, in _protect_consolidate
    result = f()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2410, in f
    self._data = self._data.consolidate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3194, in consolidate
    bm._consolidate_inplace()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3199, in _consolidate_inplace
    self.blocks = tuple(_consolidate(self.blocks))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4189, in _consolidate
    _can_consolidate=_can_consolidate)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4212, in _merge_blocks
    new_values = new_values[argsort]
MemoryError
```

Comment: What exactly is `data[predictors]` and `data['ED2']`?

Comment: `data` is the name of pandas DataFrame. I've converted the columns being used to integers. So `data[predictors]` are the columns I'm using for training and `data['ED2']` is the column I want to predict.

Comment: `fit() is supposed to take a `[x, y]` typ list as its first argument and since you're poking in `predictors` as a key to `data` I got confused. Then again that might be pandas magic/logic and then I can't help you.

Comment: By stating `data[predictors]` I've given all the necessary columns to the fit. I've a thought of a workaround and I'm currently researching on it. I'm thinking of slicing the data and iteratively training the same algorithm multiple times. For example, I spice the data into 10 parts containing 20,000 rows each and iteratively train the algorithm to complete 200,000 rows. Is that possible? If yes, can you help me with that?

Comment: I would probably 'page'  the data as well, just to see if it's the amount of data causing the issue or a loop somewhere that just don't like the data. I think you're on your own on this one. I have little experience with pandas.